# SPErrorGizmoInstallNeverFinishedErrorMessag error in iwatch app

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit, xcode-6.2, ios8.2

I am working on a iwatch app . when i am runing app getting this error . why this error is coming how to solve.

```
SPErrorGizmoInstallNeverFinishedErrorMessag
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens when you have created duplicate scheme and selecting that and executing your project.

So go to Inside your active-scheme change the target to the correct one.